# A skin material is used for both head and ears but it doesn't look the same

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I've used the same material for both the head and the ear but it doesn't look like the same material and I wonder what would be the problem.
I'd appreciate anyone who could help me with this issue.
Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Don't put the external link into the question, please use the internal functions to place images directly in your question as @MartynasŽiemys did with his edit. Oh, and now you did - but please check the most recent version of your question before everything is doubled. (Martynas: I always prefer to inform the author to edit the question, this way he can learn how to do these things on this site - and it avoids double edits.)

Comment: Sorry about my laziness. @YasharMahmoodi I hope you don't mind my edit. It's always better to just show the images instead of forcing people to click trough links - you have better chances to get more and better quality answers.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Yeah, don't mind I've now taken out the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like subsurface scattering. It looks different depending on thickness of the object. It's not standard Blender's shader so it's hard to say how it works, but I would try to play with whatever is called "Deep" in the node group or maybe I would just
use Principled BSDF instead of whatever this is.